# Use Action Bar Back Icon as back Button

Tags: java, android

**I want to use ActionBar Icon as back button to go to previous activity which an fragment**

---

```
public class Pride_big extends AppCompatActivity {

private final String Pride_big_Html = "<body><h1>Pride</h1><p>" +
        "Plot No. 37, Sector 5, Kharghar, Navi Mumbai - 410210."
        +"</body>";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pride_big);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: after setting toolbar to activity use `gegetSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`. and  check up navigation int the android docs

Comment: Have a look at 
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Comment: You need to add more details, you launched this activity from fragment?

Comment: yes  i launch my activity from fragment

Comment: Thanks sergio Lima that help